# Easy way to set elements in top 0.005% of an array to 1 and the rest to zero

Tags: python, numpy

`

```
thoughtx=frame[:,:thought1.shape[1]]


thiss=thoughtx.flatten()
index=heapq.nlargest(round(0.005*256*144*3),thiss )
thoughtx.shape=(1,256,144,3)
```

`i am looking for an efficient way to select all the elements of an 4D  array within the top 0.005% in value and replace them with ones while simultaneously converting the rest of the entries to zero's?

I have tried using nlargest above but it seems to return a list. i was hoping it would return a soft copy of the original array and then i would modify it by proxy.

Comment: Could you add input array and desired output array format? and the code you've tried; to make it a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *within the top 0.005% in value* - is it mean grater than maximum * (1 - 5e-5) ?

Comment: ah you should explicietly mention you have not a flat array, but an at lest 3D array. `thoughtx.shape=(1,256,144,3)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def top_n_percent(array, n):
    threshold = (1 - n) *  max(np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(array)))
    return np.where(array > threshold, 1, 0)
```

e.g.

```
top_n_percent([1, 0.99996, 0.99994, 0.5], 0.00005)
## array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Your formulation

> within the top 0.005% in value

is everything else than clear.
Does it mean max value is put to 1 and any values in array bigger than 0.995% of that value should be put to 1 regardless how many those are? (it could be that all values are bigger than 
Or does it mean from all n elements only those belonging to the top 0.99995 should be expressed as 1 and all others as 0?

Comment: I got the following error when i tried your code, thanks for it btw `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: did you use exactly my code? my code returns what I indicated. did you use some other array? maybe you used a numpy array? if numpy array, use instead of max(array) simply `np.max(array)`.

Comment: hm but no, this works also with np array. maybe you have a nested list?

Comment: I use python3 nd not python2

Comment: maybe the version of python is different?

Comment: do you have a version or modification needed for python 2?

Comment: I think it is because your final array is different. or if you exactly typed what I have given as code - then it must be python version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare to the 99.5% quantile (assuming you mean top 0.5%):

```
(thoughtx>np.quantile(thoughtx,0.995)).astype(<your_preferred_dtype>)
```